# Google Search Console API Credentials

Tags: ruby, google-search-console

I'm wanting to connect to the Google Search Console API via the ruby client. To do so requires credentials to authenticate.

The API calls would be made from an AWS Lambda function frequently to access data on my own Google account.

I was hoping I could simply create a Google Service Account key - however when creating one, a Role is required and there is no roles related to Search Console.

I don't want to be using OAuth Client ID credentials as there is no UI interface for the app.

How can I authenticate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the API requires an OAuth Access Token - what I really needed however was a refresh token as they don't expire and can be used to get an access token every time the script ran.

You can use Googles OAuth Playground to generate a token.

1. Create a Google App Console - https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard > create an app > Enable the APIs you want > go to credentials > Create Credentials > OAuth Client Id > Other > Copy your credentials
2. Edit the credential and add the authorized redirect URI https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground
3. Go to https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground
4. Click the settings icon > check "Use your own OAuth credentials" and set your OAuth Client credentials from step 1.
5. Select the scopes you want
6. Exchange authorization code for tokens - You now can get a refresh token that won't expire!

If you don't use the "Use your own OAuth credentials", your refresh token will expire after 24 hours.

Comment: You are a HERO. Step 2 was different for me though - I didn't see the option to "Copy your credentials" or add an authorised redirect URI. Instead of selecting "Other" when creating a new OAuth Client ID, I selected "Web application" and the redirect URI field appeared.

Comment: Hmm, my access token expired after an hour or so. Do you know how to request a new one through an API? Presumably using the refresh token?

Comment: Answered my own question: I have to grab a new token with a POST to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token with these body params:
{ client_id, client_secret, refresh_token, grant_type: "refresh_token" }